# What is the difference between model.attributes = hash vs model.attribute = value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the difference between

```
t = Zombie.find(3)
t.attributes = {:graveyard => "Benny Hills Memorial"}
t.save
```

And

```
t = Zombie.find(3)
t.graveyard = "Benny Hills Memorial"
t.save
```

railsforzombies Question 1.5. The first one works, the second doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `graveyard` attribute might not have been `attr_accessible`.